# MySQL seems to ignore single column index for composite index when sorting by primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

If I have a table such as

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
    A TINYINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    B TINYINT NOT NULL,
    C TINYINT NOT NULL,
    D TINYINT NOT NULL,
    INDEX (B),
    INDEX (C),
    INDEX (D),
    INDEX (B, C, D)
);
);
```

If I then write a query such as

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE B = 1
ORDER BY A DESC;
```

With certain data sets, MySQL seems to default to using filesort instead of just using the single column index on column B.

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | foo | ref | B,B_2 | B_2 | 1 | const | 2 | 100 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | A | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | B | 1 | B | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | C | 1 | C | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | D | 1 | D | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | B_2 | 1 | B | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | B_2 | 2 | C | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| foo | 1 | B_2 | 3 | D | A | 4 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |

Note that if INDEX HINTS are used, then it does use the single column and no longer uses filesort, which seems to be better. I'd like MySQL to figure that out though.

```
explain extended
SELECT * FROM foo USE INDEX (B)
WHERE B = 1
ORDER BY A DESC;
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | foo | ref | B | B | 1 | const | 2 | 100 | Using where |

Comment: Indexing for 'Order BY' with the combination of 'WHERE' works differently. Please go through the below link for more details https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

- Change `INDEX(B)` to `INDEX(B,A)`
- Use Engine=InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo`, there may be other subtle issues.
- Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for more details

Comment: I believe MySQL uses InnoDB by default which also appends the PRIMARY INDEX to each SECONDARY INDEX by default.

Comment: @KalebLoo - What version of MySQL are you using?  (The `SHOW` will confirm whether the table is InnoDB.)

Comment: 5.6. I've tried on 5.7 and 8.0 and saw the same thing. I confirmed that it is using InnoDB

Comment: @KalebLoo - Hmmm...  Maybe the `SHOW` and `JSON` would give me some other clue.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is an example problem. Because with a `TINYINT AUTO_INCREMENT` column you'll not ever have more than 127 rows in this table. Indexes don't matter much, if at all, for tables that size. Most real-world tables use `BIGINT` for their auto incrementing columns these days.

Ttrying to understand execution plans for tables that tiny is a waste of time: the query planner chooses indexes partly based cardinality statistics, and tiny tables don't have much of those. You'll learn more about index usage with a realistically-sized table.

Also, `filesort` doesn't necessarily mean "I, MySQL, am so dumb I had to write that dataset to a file system file to sort it". It means "I had to create a table-like data structure to do the sort". `filesort` isn't always as expensive as it sounds.

All that being said, for example query an index on `(B, A DESC, C, D)` will [*cover*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) your example query. It enables a query plan to random-access to the first eligible row (the first row where `B = 1`), then scan the index sequentially to get the rows in the order you requested. Then it can fetch the data from the index without going back to the table. Covering indexes can be very fast at satisfying particular queries, at the cost of storage space.

In realistically-sized tables, your index on just `(B)` is made unnecessary by your index on `(B, C, D)`. If you have very large tables (measured in hundreds of megarows) you may find some small I/O savings for some queries that use just the `(B)` index. Otherwise not.

And, try using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (just `ANALYZE` on some MySQL / MariaDB versions).  It actually runs the query and shows you the actual execution plan.

Comment: With real data and real queries, with the composite index it actually starts doing index joins as opposed to doing ref joins with the single index when I specify using USE INDEX